# hibernate and spring mvc combination is not working properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am learning spring mvc with hibernate. I have tried a tutorial where it shows with reverse engineering and hbm.xml. But I want to use annotated domain class for it. For which I am trying some but no luck. I have taken a web project in netbeans with spring and hibernate framework. When I submit the form it work fine and redirect to other page but data is not saved. Can anybody please help me on this please ? here are my attempts below ::

my project structure >>>

[image: enter code here]

my dispatcher-servlet.xml >>>

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />     
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

my application context >>

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">



</beans>
```

my web.xml >>

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml >>>

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springhibernate?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my User controller >>>

```
    @Controller
public class UserController {

   private static SessionFactory factory;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDemoForm(){        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("demoForm");        
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitDemoForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("employee") EmployeeAnnotation employee) {
        try {
            factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().
                    configure().
                    //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                    addAnnotatedClass(EmployeeAnnotation.class).
                    buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer employeeID = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("demoFormSuccess");

        return model;
    }

}
```

my EmployeeAnnotation Class (pojo) >>>

```
    import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_annotation")
public class EmployeeAnnotation {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary;  

   public EmployeeAnnotation() {}
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

my demoForm.jsp >>>

```
    <form action="/springMvcHibernate/submitDemoForm.html" method="post">

    <p>
      Firts Name : <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
    </p>
    <p>
            Salary : <input type="number" name="salary"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

my demoFormSuccess.jsp >>>

```
<body>
    <h1>ID is :: ${employee.id}</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call **session.flush()** in your submitAdmissionForm() method before calling Transaction commit(), please look at the below recommendation from Hibernate API **(Emphasis mine)**:

> Force this session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of
>   work, **before committing the transaction and closing the session**
>   (depending on flush-mode, Transaction.commit() calls this method).
>   Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
>   store with persistable state held in memory.
>
> Throws: HibernateException - Indicates problems flushing the session
>   or talking to the database.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()

P.S.: Also, in general, it is not a good practice to merge daatabase related logic into controllers, you need to follow services/DAOs to ensure that they are easily maintainable for future requirements. If it is just for your learning purpose, it is fine, you can do this.

Comment: what you can do also is add `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)` So you don't need to flush the session that can overwhelm your database. But for this you need to create a service that calls a DAO. It's not applicable for the situation above but it's a good alternative to do not call the `session.flush()`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried your solution but no luck. It is giving the following error >>  `org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured` , `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000` , `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value` , `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.model.EmployeeAnnotation]`

Comment: It says that id (primary key) is not generated, because you did not specify any strategy, so you can change your id (instance variable) as below:     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: hey solve it. problem was in the domain and creation of table.